# My tkinter get() function isn't working, idk why

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

(disclaimer: I'm not good at English, so nvm)

I recently started to learn a python GUI called tkinter.
I'm not sure why but the get() function of Entry is not working.

My Code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

var = Entry(root, width = 50).pack()
text = var.get()

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\Tkinter\Tkinter tutorial.py", line 8, in <module>
text = var.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'    <---- This this the problem
[Finished in 2.4s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['py', '-u', 'D:\\Python\\Tkinter\\Tkinter tutorial.py']]
[dir: D:\Python\Tkinter]
[path: C:\Program Files\Python37;C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts]
```

Comment: Need to separate the definition and the placement of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake.
All geometry managers return `None`. So, your variable `var` is `None` due to `.pack()`, as the result of last function is taken. Move the `.pack()` to the next line

```
var = Entry(root, width = 50)
var.pack()
```